# Number of parameters for an anonymous function in v0.4

Tags: julia, anonymous-function

I have the following in my package:

```
"""
numparameters(f)

Returns the number of parameters of `f` for the method which has the most parameters.
"""
function numparameters(f)
  if length(methods(f))>1
    warn("Number of methods for f is greater than 1. Choosing linearity based off of method with most parameters")
  end
  numparm = maximum([length(m.sig.parameters) for m in methods(f)])
  if VERSION < v"0.5-"
    return numparm
  else
    return (numparm-1) #-1 in v0.5 since it add f as the first parameter.
  end
end
```

This works for generic functions, and so it also works for anonymous functions on v0.5+. However, an anonymous function on v0.4 doesn't have methods, so this errors. I am wondering if anyone knows of a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 0.4 this should work for anonymous functions:

```
length(Base.uncompressed_ast(f.code).args[1])
```

This extracts the list of formal arguments from the AST and gets its length. However this is pretty expensive so you shouldn't do it too often.

Comment: Yeah, it's used very infrequent, and only in v0.4. Sounds like this would work fine. Let me give it a try.